# How to parse the file in a functional way if the iteration needs some state

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the txt file which contains 3 parts separated by "first:", "second:" and "third:", all three will be parsed into the case class Command.

The file format:

```
first:
blablabla
blablabla
blablabla

second:
second details blablabla

third:
third details blablabla
```

The case class Command

```
case class Command(first: Array[String],
                   second: Array[String],
                   third: Array[String])
```

when I iterate it by using scalaz stream, I need to implement imperative code and mutable data to handle it in the map method. Also, I need a state value, which can tell iterator which line should be put into which ListBuffer.

```
val firstListBuffer = new ListBuffer[String]
val secondListBuffer = new ListBuffer[String]
val thirdListBuffer = new ListBuffer[String]

var parsingState = ""

io.linesR("testdata/fahrenheit.txt")
    .filter(s => !s.trim.isEmpty)
    .map(t => {
   //if it is first, parsingState = "first"
   //if parsingState = "first", firstListBuffer += t
   //if it is second, parsingState = "second"
   //if parsingState = "second", secondListBuffer += t
   //if it is third, parsingState = "third"
   //if parsingState = "third", thirdListBuffer += t
})
```

I just wonder how should I refactor this one to be more functional ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I would look at writing a tail recursive function to build the corresponding `ListBuffer`. You can pass in the `command` case class and the `parsingState` as parameters to your tail recursive function.

Comment: In cases like this `map` isn't the right tool, since it can't change the "shape" of the stream—it just operates on individual elements one-by-one. You might want to start with something like `io.linesR(...).split(_.nonEmpty)`, or by writing a parser for individual blocks that you can compose sequentially with `++`.

Comment: I am not familiar with Scalaz streams, but what you want to do looks an awful lot like a fold.

Answer (score -1):

```
abstract class ParsingState
case class First extends ParsingState
case class Second extends ParsingState
case class Third extends ParsingState
case class Command(first:String, second:String, third:String) 

def read(fileName:scala.io.Source):Command = { 
@tailrec
def helper(c:Command) = { 
  val p:ParsingState = //read heading, perform custom logic to assign the correct case class
  val newStrings:String = //read strings after heading, until we hit a new heading, need to return if EOF is hit
  p match { 
    case First => helper(Command(c.first + newStrings,c.second,c.third))
    case Second => helper(Command(c.first,c.second + newStrings, c.third))
    case Third => helper(Command(c.first,c.second,c.third + newStrings))
  } 
}    
helper(Command("","",""))
}
```

NOTE:

I did not run this through the scalac, I am coding this inside of the Stackoverflow textbox. I encourage other people to crib this code and make it better as a solution, as it is incomplete and I do not have access to a Scala compiler right now. This is solution has a functional paradigm in mind though.